# What is the simplest way to calculate the amount of even numbers in a range in java

Tags: java

What is the simplest way to calculate the amount of even numbers in a range of unsigned integers?

An example: if range is (0,4) then it should return 3.

I'm having hard time to think of any simple way. The only solution I came up involved couple of if-statements. Is there a simple line of code that can do this without if-statements or ternary operator.

```
public static int countEvens(int first, int last)
{
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = first; i <= last; i++)
        count += i%2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        return count;

}
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
last / 2 - (first + 1) / 2 + 1
```

Comment: +1 This checks out for all odd/even combinations of first,last.

Comment: It doesn't work for negative numbers, but the question DOES specify "unsigned".

Comment: Thanks, only positive numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

The number of evens from 0 to the first number is:

```
num_evens_first = (first/2 + 1)
```

The number of evens from 0 to the last number is:

```
num_evens_last = (last/2 + 1)
```

The number of evens in the range would be the difference between these two number PLUS 1 if the first number itself is even.  Putting this altogether, you can use this formula:

```
num_evens_last - num_evens_first + (first + 1)%2
```

Or all at one time:

```
(last/2 + 1) - (first/2 + 1) + (first + 1)%2
```

Simplified:

```
last/2 - first/2 + (first + 1)%2
```

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of numbers in your range is even, you have n / 2 even numbers in it.

If it is odd, you have n / 2 rounded down if `first` is odd and n / 2 rounded up if `first` is even.

Comment: why the downvote? explain please so i can learn from my mistakes :)

Comment: In the case in the question, the size of the range is 4 and there are 3 even numbers in it.

Comment: @DavidWallace The size of the range is 5: 0,1,2,3,4 (even numbers are 0,2,4)

Comment: 4 - 0 = 4.  "Range" means "difference".  If you mean something else, you should spell it out more clearly.